# How can I create a grammar rule for an error?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison

I am writing a compiler in C, and I use bison for the grammar and flex for the tokens. To improve the quality of error messages, some common errors need to appear in the grammar. This has the side effect, however, of bison thinking that an invalid input is actually valid.

For example, consider this grammar:

```
program
  : command ';' program
  | command ';'
  | command {yyerror("Missing ;.");} // wrong input
  ;
command
  : INC
  | DEC
  ;
```

where `INC` and `DEC` are tokens and `program` is the initial symbol. In this case, `INC;` is a valid program, but `INC` is not, and an error message is generated. The function `yyparse()`, however, returns 0 as if the program were correct.

Looking at the bison manual, I found the macro `YYERROR`, which should behave as if the parser itself found an error. But even if I add `YYERROR` after the call to `yyerror()`, the function `yyparse()` still returns 0. I could use `YYABORT` instead, but that would stop on the first error, which is terrible and not what I want.

Is there anyway to make `yyparse()` return 1 without stopping on the first error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you intend to recover from syntax errors, you're not going to be able to use the return code from `yyparse` to signal that one or more errors occurred. Instead, you'll have to track that information yourself.

The traditional way to do that would be to use a global error count (just showing the crucial pieces):

```
%{
    int parse_error_count = 0;
%}
%%
program: statement { yyerror("Missing semicolon");
                     ++parse_error_count; }
%%
int parse_interface() {
  parse_error_count = 0;
  int status = yyparse();
  if (status) return status;        /* Might have run out of memory */
  if (parse_error_count) return 3;  /* yyparse returns 0, 1 or 2 */
  return 0;
}
```

A more modern solution is to define an additional "out" parameter to yyparse:

```
%parse-param { int* error_count }
%%
program: statement { yyerror("Missing semicolon");
                     ++*error_count; }
%%
int main() {
  int error_count = 0;
  int status = yyparse(&error_count);
  if (status || error_count) { /* handle error */ }
```

Finally, in case you really need to export the symbol `yyparse` from your bison-generated code, you can do the following ugly hack:

```
%code top {
#define yyparse internal_yyparse
}
%parse-param { int* error_count }
%%
program: statement { yyerror("Missing semicolon");
                     ++*error_count; }
%%
#undef yyparse
int yyparse() {
  int error_count = 0;
  int status = internal_yyparse(&error_count);
  // Whatever you want to do as a summary
  return status ? status : error_count ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: While I cannot modify the main() function (this is for a course at the university), I managed to call `YYABORT` after the initial symbol when `error_count > 0`. Dirty, but works.

Comment: @mgmillani: You can do it without modifying the main function, simply by giving `yyparse` a different name (say `internal_yyparse`) and then defining your own `yyparse` which calls the bison-generated one. I'll modify the example to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`yyerror()` just prints an error message. It doesn't alter what `yyparse()` returns.

What you're attempting is not a good idea. You'll enormously expand the grammar and you run a major risk of making it ambiguous. All you need to do is *remove* the production that calls `yyerror()`. That input will produce a syntax error anyway, and that will cause `yyparse()` not to return 0. You're keeping a dog and barking yourself. What you should be checking for is *semantic* errors that the parser can't see.

If you really want to improve the error messages, there's enough information in the parse tables and state information to tell you what the expected next token was. However in most cases it's such a large set it's pointless to print it. But programmers are used to sorting out 'syntax error'. Don't sweat it. Writing compilers is hard enough already.

NB You should make your grammar left-recursive to avoid excessive stack usage: for example, `program : program ';' command`.